# Adding a mail to function to an already exsisting PHP script

Tags: php, scripting

I have created a petition website with PHP scripting that allowas the signer to sign the petiion an display it in the backoffice of my site. What I am looking to accomplish is adding a mail function to the script so it will email the signers information as well as a time stamp, ip address, and user agent id to my email address. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. I am new to PHP and teaching myself how do code.

```
<?php
include('database/config.php');
include('database/database.php');

$err = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){        

    $first = addslashes(trim($_POST['first'])); 

    $last = addslashes(trim($_POST['last']));   

    $glvar = addslashes(trim($_POST['glvar']));

    $ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    //echo $ip;

     if(($first!='')&& ($last!='')&& ($glvar!='')){ 

        $database = new Database(HOST, DATEBASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);   

        $allUsers = $database->select('user','glvar_id','*',"glvar_id = '".$glvar."'");
        //echo $ip;     

        $checkglvar = 0;            
    $checkglvar = count($allUsers); 

        $userData = array(              
            'first_name' => $first, 
            'last_name' => $last,               
            'glvar_id' => $glvar,       
            'ip' => $ip,        

        );      

        if(!$checkglvar) {          

            $database->insert('user',$userData);

            mail("info@mysite.com", "Subject", "message");

            header('location:thank-you.html');      

        }    else  $err.='<p style="color:red">Ooops! You have already signed the petition</p>';        

    } else {    

        if($first=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your First Name is empty</p>';   

        if($last=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your Last Name is empty</p>'; 

        if($glvar=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your GLVAR ID is empty</p>'; 

    }

}
```

Comment: use `mail()` function

Comment: I have that function, but how do I define the email setup with the time stamp, ip address, and user agent ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mail("info@mysite.com", "Subject", "message");
```

You can make the "Subject" and "message" be anything that you want. Think of it as the 3 fields in an email ("To:", "Subject Line", "Contents of the email").

So you can create a variable to be emailed to you like:

```
$message = "IP: $ip" . PHP_EOL;
$message .= "TIME: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$message .= "UserAgent: $glvar_id" . PHP_EOL;

mail("to@me.com", "Subject of email", $message);
```

This would send you an email looking like:

```
Subject: Subject of email 
Contents:  
IP: 127.0.0.1 
Time: 2013-06-21 12:30:12
UserAgent: whatever-this-id-looks-like
```

By the way, I have no idea what you meant by user agent ID, so I used the $glvar_id as the UserAgent, but I doubt that is correct

Answer (score 0):

here is how to use the mail function with headers attached. headers are separated with `\r\n`

```
 $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
 $subject = 'the subject';
 $message = 'hello';
 $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mail("users_email@site.com", "Whatever subject you want", "Thanks, blah blah blah\nIP Address: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\nDate" . date("M j Y @ H:i:s") . "\nUser Agent: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "From: you@yoursite.com");`

Not sure if you need a human readable date or a unix timestamp, if you need the timestamp replace with time() instead of the [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.  Check out the date() documentation for different formatting.  And the "\n" are newline characters (just in case you were not aware).

I noticed in your code you were not sending any headers.  The 4th param in the code above ("From: you@yoursite.com"), will add a From field to the email, makes it look better in the inbox.

Comment: I follow your scripting, but Im still very new to this and confused how to add their name and glvar ID as well. I appreciate your help with all of this.